# Flying wing airfoil

Tags: airfoil, flying-wing

What would be let say some of appropriate airfoils for flying wing RC model ? Wingspan arround 1200mm and speed arround 700 km/h.
Maybe MH64 or so ?

Thank you,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Drones.SE instead.

Comment: @Toni Bitenc 700 km/hr?

Comment: Tried migrating this 3 times, and it's just closed.  SE bug perhaps.

Comment: Why so many negative answers here? Could you explain please? I dont understand...:

Comment: 700 km/h is very fast for rc aircraft, but not totally out of question. A couple of years ago, rc Jets exceeding 700 kmh/h (https://youtu.be/uCH64yciiq8) apeared

Comment: Just out of curiosity how is your project going to look like? :-)

Comment: Hello, for now it looks it wil be 60degree  triangle :-)) What to say :-)))

Comment: Challenging and therefore interesting project :-)  How are you going to control it? Horten airfoils are also definitely worth a look. Or, more generally, reflexed airfoils (but I suppose you already know this)

Comment: Thank you for your replay,   :-))) Headacke headacke :-))) For sure electronic will be needed to contro it for this speeds .

Comment: If you use reflexed airfoils it should remain self-stable. Does it have to fly so fast for a contest?

Comment: Hello, no contest just for fun

Answer (score 4):

I recommend one that has been used successfully before, and at up to 1000 km/h airspeed: The [Göttingen 765](https://www.aerodesign.de/profile/data/goe765_pol.gif) ([source](https://www.aerodesign.de/profile/data/goe765_pol.gif)).

[image: XFOIL data for the Gö 765]

Used as a root airfoil on the DfS 94 and 194 (aka Me 163 A). The root airfoil on the Me 163 B was 0.4% thinner, but otherwise very similar.

Comment: Thank you Peter
Will check also other topics as Im new here and will be back